# Haskell sum of generated list

Tags: list, haskell, sum

Hi i'm pretty new to haskell and I want to make a program with prime numbers.
With the code below I put all the prime numbers between 2 integers in a list, now i want to make a sum of all the prime numbers of the generated list and show this as an answer.

```
primesR :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
primesR a b = takeWhile (<= b) $ dropWhile (< a) $ sieve [2..]
  where sieve (n:ns) = n:sieve [ m | m <- ns, m `mod` n /= 0 ]
```

I didn't find any examples of the sum of a generated list. Does anyone know how I can manage this in the code?

thx

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `sum` function, like so:

```
primesR :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
primesR a b = sum $ takeWhile (<= b) $ dropWhile (< a) $ sieve [2..]
       where sieve (n:ns) = n:sieve [ m | m <- ns, m `mod` n /= 0 ]
```

Note that you need to change the function signature from `Integral a => a -> a -> [a]` to `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, since the result of summation is a single value, not a list.